# Do i need a British transit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas, schengen-visas

I am an Indian Citizen travelling from **Mumbai(India) to Berlin(Germany)** via **British Airways** which goes from **Mumbai to London.**

I already have a **Schengen visa C-Type**

Do I need a British Transit visa in this case?

Just to clarify **i am not stopping at London**. My destination is Berlin. But the British airways flight goes from Mumbai to London with a stop in Berlin.

Comment: So can you clarify your journey? Mumbai - Berlin - London - Berlin?

Comment: Mumbai-London-Berlin

Comment: So you are stopping in London then?

Comment: only at the airport for a connecting flight. There was some miscommunication with my parents who had originally asked this question. They will be at the London airport to catch a connecting flight to Berlin

Comment: Then the duplicate applies to you

Comment: The itinerary described in the last paragraph of the orignal question ("...with a stop in Berlin.") is (at best) unclear, or (at worst) wrong. Based on what the OP says in these Comments, I think the OP's itinerary is Mumbai > London > Berlin.